# How to colour the area under a graph in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

[image]

How can I know color the are of the parabola, say, of the positive x values? I'm using Inkscape for creating the figures.

Comment: Hi but the graph it is done in LaTeX :-) and there are many solution directly in LaTeX to solve your problem.

Comment: @Sebastiano the huge advantage of inkscape is that you can create graphs or figures of any kind (especially good for differential geometry and topology) insanely quick.

Comment: I am agree with you. I use Adobe Illustrator to do quick improved for the code that I have created. I not understand the reason of your downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**
I just used the Bezier tool to fit the desired area under the curve and then filled this selected are with the colour of choice.

[image]

Comment: Hi Hilberto, welcome to GDSE. Please don't forget to choose your own answer as best!

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it this way:

- draw a straight line to connect the curve with your `x`-axis (press `F6` and keep `Ctrl` pressed to ensure the line is straight)
- use the `fill bounded areas` tool (paintbucket icon, the `U` hotkey) by clicking anywhere on the enclosed area formed by the curve, the axis, and the line you just drew